# Using lodash for a MobX store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, mobx

I'm using `lodash` together with `mobx` to retrieve data, looks something like this:

```
_.get(store, "prop.arr[0].subProp")
```

Works fine, but `mobx` gives me warnings in the case `arr` is `undefined` or empty:

`Attempt to read an array index (0) that is out of bounds (0). Please check length first. Out of bound indices will not be tracked by MobX`

Is there any workaround for this? I don't want to add the length check, want to keep it as a one-liner.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like _.get(store, "prop.arr ? prop.arr[0].subProp : null") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before passing the `store` to `get`, pass through `toJS` utility by mobx. This should resolve it.

so your one liner would be - `_.get(toJS(store), "prop.arr[0].subProp")`

more on `toJS` here - https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html